# computing the determinants of matrices in an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Say you have a numpy array of matrices e.g. an array of dimension (n,m,m). Think of it as n matrices each of size mxm. Is there a way (not using a loop) of computing the determinant of each each matrix in one go?

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? I found this question and answer very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the determinant of numpy arrays using[`numpy.linalg.det`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html) as shown below:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
M = 4

# Generate N random MxM arrays
arrays = np.array([np.random.random((M,M)) for _ in range(N)])

dets = np.linalg.det(arrays)
print(dets)
# array([-0.20353081,  0.01632881, -0.17733447, -0.01518313, -0.23457492,
#        0.00284906,  0.16210605,  0.03887231,  0.07726804, -0.05107936])
```

In the example above I have 10 matrices of size 4x4 (randomly generated as an example). `dets` is a numpy array of 10 numbers, your determinants.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy there's a fucntion called "**linalg.det**" :

Per example :

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[-2,2,-3],[-1,1,3],[2,0,-1]])
np.linalg.det(m)
```

see the doc of *linalg.det* here :
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html